# How does the package pst-labo work to draw chemical equipment?

Tags: pstricks, chemistry

I would like to draw some chemical equipment and I found this `pst-labo` package. However, it does not work for me and I am sure I have the package installed.

This should be a very simple example of its usage which does not work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\title{Blank}
\date{April 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pstTubeEssais

\end{document}
```

Comment: How are you trying to compile the document? `pdflatex`? `pstricks` (the package working behind the scenes) requires `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` to be used.

Comment: Or you can add `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` to your preamble, and compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: By adding `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` to my preamble to the code showed before still reports error and does not compile with PdfLaTeX.

Comment: If you go back to the original code, does `latex` work?

Answer (score 1):

Run the document with `xelatex` (without loading package `inputenc`) or run it with  `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` with loading package `auto-pst-pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\title{Blank}
\date{April 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{postscript}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pstTubeEssais
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

My output with `xelatex` and current TeXLive 2013

[image]

Comment: Using that code and compiling with pdflatex still does not show the equipment figure. Texkstudio says: `auto-pst-pdf: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}`. Furthermore, copying the code also into sharelatex does not show the figure either.

Comment: I suppose that you are missing the option `--shell-escape`. Howver, can't you use `xelatex` then there is no need for using `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: Even using `xelatex` I cannot see the equipment. Did you try the code personally?

Comment: see my added image in my answer

Comment: That works for me using `xelatex` from texlive 2014. I had to change the `postscript` to `pspicture` though.

Comment: that depends on how you want to use the macros.